# StringBuilder Extension Append Call Resolution

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, extension-methods, stringbuilder

I've got an extension method that appends each object in an IEnumerable to a StringBuilder. It operates on IEnumerable with the type argument, though, so my question is will it trigger the Append() calls unique to separate types or will *everything* pass through as "object" and be inefficient? If I need to, I'll expand the function for special cases where StringBuilder has Append() calls unique to the type, but I need to know if I have to do it or not.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Appends each object in the enumerable to the StringBuilder's content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="sb"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"/>
    public static StringBuilder AppendEach<T>(this StringBuilder sb, IEnumerable<T> e)
    {
        e.Do<T>(t => sb.Append(t));
        return sb;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows you to run code on each value in a collection in-line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="t"></param>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    public static void Do<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T t in e) action(t);
    }
```

Wasn't sure if the Do extension I was using would change the outcome of the question, so I included it instead of simplifying the code. I know some people would hang me for writing "LINQ methods with side effects" here, but that's not relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will call `Append(Object)` if you meant that by "will it trigger the Append() calls unique to separate types".

Since there happens to be a dispute. C# compiler must decide which method to use at compile time. It means that the chosen methods parameters must not conflict with variables you put in Append(...). Since the compiler does not know what T is at compile time it will choose `Append(object)` because it is the only one that will work whatever T is gonna be.

I've imitated the scenario:

```
public class C
{
public static void Show(object value)
{
    "object".Dump();
}

public static void Show(int value)
{
    "int".Dump();
}

public static void Show(string value)
{
    "string".Dump();
}
}

public class MyClass<T>
{
   public void Append(T value)
   {
C.Show(value);
   }
}

public void Main()
{
var c1 = new MyClass<int>();
var c2 = new MyClass<string>();
var c3 = new MyClass<object>();

c1.Append(1);
c2.Append("1");
c3.Append(2);
}
```

It shows "object" 3 times.

BTW. If you remove the object-method from the class it will not compile for it won't be able to find a suitable method.

Comment: This is not quite right for his case -- see my answer.

Comment: The reason why was articulated well by @Servy in a comment on another answer: "the method is not dynamically bound", "generics are a compile-time concept." I added overloads for each type supported by StringBuilder and kept the original as a fallback and to handle object types.

Answer (score -4):

Leaving this here for the sake of discussion unless someone sees fit to remove it -- but the information here is incorrect.

> Everything will not pass through as "object" -- everything will pass through as whatever T happens to be (or the most-specific superclass of T that StringBuidler has an Append() call for).
>
> So, if you pass in an IEnumerable, every item in that enumerable will be passed to the Append(object) override, because the compiler doesn't know enough to call a more specific override.
>
> However, if you pass in an IEnumerable, then Append(string) will be called, because the compiler now knows enough about the type to select the proper override.
>
> If you pass in an IEnumerable but every object in the enumerable is a string, it will still call the Append(object) override because the type information is lost.

Comment: OK that's what I thought when I originally wrote it. Since there seems to be some disagreement I'll wait a few more minutes before choosing this as the answer to let others weigh in.

Comment: The method is not dynamically bound.  It doesn't do this.  Generics are a compile time concept.

Comment: @Yushatak It's not what it does at all.  It's just flat wrong.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps you could articulate how it does operate and why this is wrong in an answer so I can select it?

Comment: @Yushatak You could write the simple test yourself.  You've already written the code in fact.  Run it and see which overload is called.

Comment: @Servy Should have understood when you said "generics are a compile-time concept", which I knew but wasn't thinking about properly. All makes sense and confirmed via a test console app that you are correct.

Comment: I see what you're saying -- I assumed that since the information is there at compile time (via generics), the compiler would have enough information to select the proper overload at compile-time. A quick test confirms I'm dead wrong there.